# convert s800 shared executable binary file to PA-RISC1.0 shared executable dynamically linked

Tags: linux, unix

I have a binary executable dynamically linked file in Unix and it gives me the output
When I run the same in Linux it doesn't run and gives me below error
"cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

The file type I have in unix is s800 shared executable dynamically linked -not stripped

The file type I have in Linux is PA-RISC1.0 shared executable dynamically linked - not stripped

I need this executable file to run in Linux

Comment: You most likely need to compile your linux program on your linux machine, so it generates the correct binary format. For instance, what does `file /bin/ls` output? Is it the same PA-RISC1.0 type? Probably not. If it does, then you should edit your question about to include the exact error message that is generated by you PA-RISC1.0 system. (DON"T POST ERROR MSGS IN COMMENTS! (please!) ) . Good luck.

Comment: S800 is HP9000 server, right? It is based on PA-RISK. On what platform is based your Linux?